# Android Listview scroll lag with view holder

Tags: android, listview, android-volley

I have noticed that a ListView in my application has started to stutter quite badly all of a sudden.

I am using Volley to load images for my listview items - downloading and caching the images are fine and scroll smooth as butter.

However I currently have a spinner that sits on top of the NetworkImageView while I wait for the image to load. The lag comes in once the image has successfully loaded - I set the spinner to be invisible and the image to visible. Changing the visibility of these items seems to be the source of the lag.

I **am** currently using the View Holder pattern, my onResponseLoad looks like the following:

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                if (response.getBitmap() != null){ //Check that the image is not null
                    ProgressBar progress = holder.getProgress(); //Find Spinner - this doesnt cause lag
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Hide spinner (This causes lag)
                    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Image is a network image from the holder (This causes lag)
                }
            }
```

(Note that commenting out those two offending lines results in buttery smooth scrolling again)

The other strange thing is that I haven't touched this part of the application in some time and in my current live version, as well as previous commits there is no lag. Comparing my current code base to previous non-lagging versions show that there has been 0 change to the code surrounding this aspect of the application. Furthermore other lists that I have implemented using almost the exact same technique have not experienced this issue.

The only thing I can think of that could be different is that I am now using the latest version of Gradle - although I don't think that should have an impact at run-time.

I am at a total loss as to what is going on, would appreciate any insight on what I should be doing to achieve smooth ListView scrolling (or what may have lead to my implementation's degradation)

EDIT: Posting code of getView() as requested

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View placeSelectorView = convertView;
    PlaceViewHolder placeSelectorHolder = null;

    if(placeSelectorView == null){ //If we are creating the row for the first time
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); //Inflate the view

        placeSelectorView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_selector, parent, false); //Get the view

        placeSelectorHolder = new PlaceViewHolder(placeSelectorView); //Create holder object
        placeSelectorView.setTag(placeSelectorHolder); //Attach reference to the view
    }else{
        placeSelectorHolder = (PlaceViewHolder) placeSelectorView.getTag(); //Load holder from memory
        if(!placeSelectorHolder.isHasImage()){ //Need to optimise this
            placeSelectorHolder.getLayout().addView(placeSelectorHolder.getrLayoutThumbnail(), 0);
            placeSelectorHolder.setHasImage(true);
        }

        if(!placeSelectorHolder.isSpinnerVisible()){
            placeSelectorHolder.getProgressBar().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            placeSelectorHolder.getPlaceImg().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            placeSelectorHolder.setSpinnerVisible(true);
        }
    }

    POI place = (values.get(position)); //Get POI object for the place
    POI parentPlace = getParent(place); //Get parent POI for place
    placeSelectorHolder.getPlaceName().setText(place.getName());


    if(parentPlace != null){ //If place has a parent POI
        placeSelectorHolder.getParentPlaceName().setText(parentPlace.getName());
    }else{ //We don't want the parent text in the view
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) placeSelectorHolder.getParentPlaceName().getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.weight = 0; //Setting weight to 0 will remove it from the LinearLayout
        placeSelectorHolder.getParentPlaceName().setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    final PlaceViewHolder holder = placeSelectorHolder;
    loadThumbnail(holder, place);

    return placeSelectorView;
}

public void loadThumbnail(final PlaceViewHolder placeSelectorHolder, POI place){
    RealmList<poiPhoto> photos = place.getPhotos();
    String mUrl;

    if(!photos.isEmpty()){
        mUrl = photos.get(0).getSmall();
    }else{
        mUrl = "";
    }

    final NetworkImageView placeImg = placeSelectorHolder.getPlaceImg();
    if(!mUrl.equals("")){ //If there is an Image Available
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ServerSingleton.getInstance(getContext()).getImageLoader(); //Get volley imageloader from Singleton
        imageLoader.get(mUrl, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() { //Custom get so we can use override onResponse and OnErrorResponse

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                if (response.getBitmap() != null){ //Check that the image is not null
                    ProgressBar progressBar = placeSelectorHolder.getProgressBar(); //Find Spinner
                    placeImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(progressBar != null) progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Make the spinner invisible
                    placeSelectorHolder.setSpinnerVisible(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //TO-DO: Get an error image
            }
        });

        placeImg.setImageUrl(mUrl, imageLoader); //Send the request
        placeSelectorHolder.setHasImage(true);
    }else{ //There is no image
        LinearLayout layout = placeSelectorHolder.getLayout(); //Find the horizontal layout
        layout.removeView(placeSelectorHolder.getrLayoutThumbnail()); //Remove the Thumbnail layout
        placeSelectorHolder.setHasImage(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry Done, thanks!

Comment: Try to set Fix height and width to image

Comment: @Anil Currently have a fixed height and width of 40dp with ScaleType of fitXY. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I think Anil means a fixed height on your image, not just your ImageView. If you set a scale type Android has to scale your image, which takes time. Try to download your images at the size of the View you are going to put them in to maximize performance.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry Thanks for the clarification - I tried it without success. Funnily enough, I built a release and it runs as smooth as ever. It seems to only be an issue in debug builds.

Must be something I am completely overlooking. My search continues...